# assistance in grep-ing a file for "!!!"

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am attempting to search a large file for the lines which contain the string `!!!` and output those lines to a different file.

However, the shell is interpreting the `!!!` as a shebang and inserting my previous command as the search criteria (with an extra `!` on the end)

The command I am using is:

`cat file_to_search.txt | grep "!!!" > output.txt`

Note: Using `RHEL7.7` if that makes a difference

Comment: use single quotes: `grep '!!!'`

Comment: @Peleion does not work on my system

Comment: Works fine on my Centos 7.8 exactly as you printed. `$ cat test.txt |grep '!!!'
!!! works` as does `grep \!\!\!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exclamation are a special character (negate), you will need to escape them with a "\" so that the shell uses the character literally when grepping. The following matches three exclamation points in a row (!!!) as requested:

```
cat file_to_search.txt | grep "\!\!\!" > output.txt
```

Or you could use the additional quantifier like so:

```
cat file_to_search.txt | grep "\!\{3\}" > output.txt
```

Here is a [source on Regex searches](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html), and a [special character source](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/SpecialCharacters).

Comment: Note this answer relies on the behavior of `grep`. The tool *will* get these backslashes in `\!\!\!`and only because it treats backslashes as escape characters they will not matter. Other tools (or even `grep`, try `grep -F`) may or may not treat the backslashes literally.